# Writing toml file with .Nett

Tags: vb.net, toml

I come across "toml" file from some websites and find that it is pretty good so trying to start using it. But then, I find that there is not a lot of examples of toml file.

I am now trying to use it with Nett in vb.net.
It give me a while to figure out how to read with it but, struggled with how to write the file.

Anyone can help with it?
`Nett.Toml.WriteFile(TomlTable, String)` is doing the writing but, how do I create the "TomlTable" here?

Trying to write below:

```
[TRANSFERS]
    [Transfers.0]
    Transfer_Mode="1"
    File_Type="2"
    Source_Directory="asd"
    Destination_Directory=123
    
    [Transfers.1]
    Transfer_Mode=""
    File_Type=""
    Source_Directory=""
    Destination_Directory=""
```

Comment: I've never heard of TOML or Nett but I just did a bit of searching and found [the relevant documentation](http://paiden.github.io/Nett/api/Nett.TomlTable.html). Have you read that and noted the `Add` extension methods? I would guess that that result would be achieved by adding an array of objects but I haven't done any testing to see what each of those methods do.

Comment: I tried 'Add' but, unfortunately, the code goes without error, nothing is added to the file.

Comment: You should show what you tried and you should also examine the `TomlTable` in the debugger, not just look at what gets output.